# How do I capture this mysql output message in a variable?

Tags: bash, mysql, variable

I have this line in my script:

```
mysqlinsert=$(/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysql --host=localhost -uroot -proot --password=notmyrealpassword << EOF
$mysqlrun)
```

Despite what it returns, the variable `$mysqlinsert` is always empty. I tried using `-n` (disables output buffering) for mysql and putting `EOF` after `$mysqlrun` but neither worked.

Comment: the usual suspects would be: (1) there *was no* output, and/or (2) the output went to stderr instead of stdout. During the script's execution, did any mysql output accumulate to your screen?

Comment: Another option would be that the current user could not execute `/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysql`, resulting in yet more stderr and an empty variable.

Comment: @JeffSchaller, yes I see the output on my screen. It's likely that the output went to stderr, which I tried to change with `2>&1`, it didn't work (but I may have placed this redirect in the wrong place? I put it after `$mysqlrun`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the command is sending the output you want to stderr, then redirect the command's stderr inside the command substitution:

```
mysqlinsert=$(/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysql ... 2>&1 << EOF ...)
#
#                                                     /\______addition____
```

... where I've elided some parameters to focus on the change I'm suggesting.